# how to assign a constant value to a column in oledb destination in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, oledbdestination

i have a OLE DB  destination which has a destination columns such as TrackDateTime , OperationTypeID, and TrxID  .Here TrxID i will get a value from input column. But my requirements here is to get the values for TrackDateTime , OperationTypeID : Here TrackDateTime  must be current date and time and OperationTypeID  must be 2 always. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Assume the data flow takes 10 minutes: should the TrackDateTime reflect the time the process started (2019-04-14 10:11:12.130) or should it reflect the time the batch itself was inserted (2019-04-14 10:11:12.130), 2019-04-14 10:11:12.245), 2019-04-14 10:13:51.654), etc?  A constant value can make it easier to track (and rollback) bad data but some folks want the precision of the actual time it was added. What is your business need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a derived column transformation to generate fixed values:

*TrackDateTime*

```
GETDATE()
```

or if you need the package execution date time:

```
[System::StartTime]
```

*OperationTypeID*

```
2
```

**Helpful links**

- [Derived Column Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Derived Column Transformation in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/derived-column-transformation-in-ssis/)